¿Como hacer validaciones con mas de registro en sql?
Estoy realizando un reporte donde necesito obtener aquellos registros donde su tipoVenta sea un EXCA1 o EXCA2 y que su codigoFacturable sea 0 y que sea como el siguiente ejempo:

Estoy realizando con la siguiente consulta:
select 
dcmlNumeroBoleto, strTipoDocumento, strTipoVenta, 
intCodigoFacturable 
from tblControlInterno 
where strTipoVenta in ('EXCA1', 'EXCA2') and intCodigoFacturable = 
0 and strTipoDocumento in('F', 'NC')
and convert(varchar(4),dtefechaemisionboleto,120) = '2024'
group by dcmlNumeroBoleto, strTipoDocumento, strTipoVenta, 
intCodigoFacturable

pero esta consulta me arroja registro como el siguiente:

La salida es correcta pero si busco el registro 1392144870662 individual, me da la siguiente info:

y podemos ver que tiene otros dos registros con codigoFacurable 2, ¿como puedo hacer que no me salgan esos registros desde mi primer consulta? espero me puedan apoyar en mi error.

podes dar un ejemplo de datos reales que produce eso?

Ese es un ejemplo de un dato real o a que te refieres con un dato real ?¿

No entiendo, yo no veo que salgan.. vos donde los ves?? y si, ahora pusiste un ejemplo mas real, antes no eran lo mismo, y no tenia logica lo que pedias...

Si buscas solo por número de boleto el 1392144870662 van a salir esas filas extras, pero no saldrán en la otra consulta porque intCodigoFacturable no es 0. Entonces no entiendo el problema.

Si entiendo correctamente, quieres mostrar boletos de 2024 con su data (tipo de documento, tipo de la venta, y código facturable), pero solamente si todas las filas del boleto en 2024 están de tipo de documento F/NC, tipo de la venta EXCA1/EXCA2 y código facturable 0. Si hay filas para el boleto que tiene otros datos, no quieres mostrar ninguna fila de ese boleto.
En otras palabras: Quieres ver los datos de los boletos de 2024 para los cuales no hay datos indeseables. "No hay" = NOT EXISTS en SQL.
select dcmlnumeroboleto, strtipodocumento, strtipoventa, intcodigofacturable 
from tblcontrolinterno ci
where not exists
(
  select null
  from tblcontrolinterno mal
  where mal.dcmlnumeroboleto = ci.dcmlnumeroboleto
  and
  (
    mal.strtipoventa not in ('EXCA1', 'EXCA2')
    or
    mal.strtipodocumento not in('F', 'NC')
    or
    mal.intcodigofacturable <> 0
  )
)
order by dcmlnumeroboleto, strtipodocumento, strtipoventa, intcodigofacturable;

En vez de NOT EXISTS puedes usar NOT IN, si lo prefieres.
Si es posible que campos son NULL, tienes que adaptar la consulta un poco (por ejemplo: COALESCE(mal.strtipoventa, 'NADA') NOT IN ('EXCA1', 'EXCA2')).
Si hay datos duplicados (más de una fila con la misma combinación de dcmlnumeroboleto + strtipodocumento + strtipoventa + intcodigofacturable), tienes que SELECT DISTINCT ...).

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Thorsten, me sirvio mucho y aprendí algo nuevo.
